# How to rotate a card with css transform inside memory game

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular5

I'm building a memory game in Angular. I've attached the component's logic, css and html below.
I'm trying to get the cards to flip but methods online don't work. Any suggestions on how to pull this off? 
Note that in the data structure for a card there's a isFlipped property set to false. Would appreciate any help, thanks.

```js
// angular
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

// services
import { CardService } from "../app/services/cards.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = "the tech memory game";
  tagline: string = "Time to sharpen up those memory cells!";
  cards = [];
  total_cards_count: number = 3;
  prevCard = null;
  isProcessing: boolean = false;
  flippedCouplesCount: number = 0; 

  constructor(public cardService: CardService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cards = this.cardService.getCards();
    console.log(this.cards);
  }

  playGame(card, cardDiv) {
    if (this.isProcessing) return;
    // flip card
    card.isFlipped = !card.isFlipped;
    cardDiv.classList.add('flipped');
    // compare cards and check
    if (this.prevCard) {
      if (card.name === this.prevCard.name) {
        this.prevCard = null;
        this.flippedCouplesCount++; 
      } else {
        this.isProcessing = true;
        // if no match- flip cards in 1 sec
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.prevCard.isFlipped = false;
          card.isFlipped = false;
          this.isProcessing = false;
          this.prevCard = null;
        }, 1000);
      }
    } else {
      this.prevCard = card;
    }
    if (this.total_cards_count === this.flippedCouplesCount) {
      console.log('game over');
      
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* width: 100%;  */
    /* transform: rotateY(180deg); */
}

.front {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<section>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
      Welcome to {{ title }}!
    </h1>
    <h3>{{ tagline }}</h3>
    <!-- <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="> -->
  </div>

  <!-- game board -->
    <div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let card of cards" #cardDiv (click)="playGame(card, cardDiv)" class="cardholder">
          <img src="{{ card.img }}" class="front" *ngIf="card.isFlipped"/>
          <img src="{{ card.cover }}" class="back"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can u create [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/)? For the see real application and solve the problem.

Comment: Plunker won't show any of the data coming in, which includes the cards...
But basically I've got the logic of the game done and this is just a css issue: how to flip the cards nicely. I've looked all around and tried transform: rotateY( 180deg) on some classes, adding a backface-visibility: hidden on others. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a combination of Angular animations and css animations. Adapt the following demo to your need:

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r61x5p)

**Typescript:**

```
  ...
  animations: [
    trigger('flipCard', [
      state('true', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'
      })),
      state('false', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(0)'
      })),
      transition('true => false', animate('800ms ease-out')),
      transition('false => true', animate('800ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]


...

  flip(index) {
    this.cards[index].isFlipped = !this.cards[index].isFlipped;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let card of cards; let i=index" #cardDiv class="cardholder">
        <div class="card" (click)="flip(i)" [@flipCard]="card.isFlipped">
            <div class="card-title front">
                {{card.name}} Front
            </div>
            <div class="card-title back">
                {{card.name}} Back
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 100%;  
    /* transform: rotateY(180deg); */
}

.card-wrapper {
    perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 120px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-title {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size:30px;
}

.front {
    background-color: #255C85;
}

.back {
    background-color: #ED254E;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: That nearly does it, but not quite. For some reason the cover doesn't show initially and upon flip I can see a flash of the card but then it flips to the cover...not the desired effect, obviously. 

This is the repo if you wanna have a look: 
https://github.com/CharlesMarlow/Angular5--memory-game

Comment: Gordon, check the demo again. If it still doesn't work for you could you make a demo?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[class.active]="card.isFlipped"` to add a class if card flipped. After you can bind CSS animate to these node children: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/tree/master/source/flippers
flipOutY and flipInY with delay a half of animation time.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Do you have a working example of this thing somewhere?